# How can i get the current month and previous three months using PHP

Tags: php, date

Will any one tell me how to get the current month and previous three months using PHP

For example:

```
echo date("y:M:d");
```

output will be: 09:Oct:20

But i need:

August

September

October

as the Output.

Thanks in advance...

Fero

Answer (score 32, accepted):

for full textual representation of month you need to pass "F":

```
echo date("y:F:d");
```

for previous month you can use

`echo date("y:F:d",strtotime("-1 Months"))`;

Comment: This will fail when performed on the 31st. See my answer.

Answer (score 15):

Watch out for the [FUAH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279634/cant-get-previous-month-from-datetime-in-php-is-this-a-pretty-big-bug/4280377#4280377)!  The other answers will fail when performed on the 31st of the month. Use this instead:

```
/*
Handles month/year increment calculations in a safe way,
avoiding the pitfall of 'fuzzy' month units.

Returns a DateTime object with incremented month values, and a date value == 1.
*/
function incrementDate($startDate, $monthIncrement = 0) {

    $startingTimeStamp = $startDate->getTimestamp();
    // Get the month value of the given date:
    $monthString = date('Y-m', $startingTimeStamp);
    // Create a date string corresponding to the 1st of the give month,
    // making it safe for monthly calculations:
    $safeDateString = "first day of $monthString";
    // Increment date by given month increments:
    $incrementedDateString = "$safeDateString $monthIncrement month";
    $newTimeStamp = strtotime($incrementedDateString);
    $newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $newTimeStamp);
    return $newDate;
}

$currentDate = new DateTime();
$oneMonthAgo = incrementDate($currentDate, -1);
$twoMonthsAgo = incrementDate($currentDate, -2);
$threeMonthsAgo = incrementDate($currentDate, -3);

echo "THIS: ".$currentDate->format('F Y') . "<br>";
echo "1 AGO: ".$oneMonthAgo->format('F Y') . "<br>";
echo "2 AGO: ".$twoMonthsAgo->format('F Y') . "<br>";
echo "3 AGO: ".$threeMonthsAgo->format('F Y') . "<br>";
```

For more, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279634/cant-get-previous-month-from-datetime-in-php-is-this-a-pretty-big-bug/4280377#4280377)

Answer (score 6):

this month

```
date("y:M:d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y')));
```

previous months

```
date("y:M:d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') - 1, date('d'), date('Y')));
date("y:M:d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') - 2, date('d'), date('Y')));
```

Comment: yours this answer produces PARSE ERROR

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in E:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\test_Fero\test.php on line 3

Comment: If you count the opening-brackets `(` you'll find there are five in each line, but only four closing-brackets. If you balance the two, five of each, the code should work.

Comment: Looks like you need another closing ")" before the semicolon.

Comment: @Fero add an extra ')' at the end of the lines before the semicolons.

Comment: This does not work on the last day of the month. Running `date("y:M:d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') - 1, date('d'), date('Y')))` on May 31 results in `12:May:01`

Answer (score 3):

Try using the built in [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function in PHP and using 'F' for full textual output:

```
echo date('y:F:d'); // first month
echo date('y:F:d', strtotime('-1 month')); // previous month
echo date('y:F:d', strtotime('-2 month')); // second previous month
echo date('y:F:d', strtotime('-3 month')); // third previous month
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be OOP about it, try this:

```
$dp=new DatePeriod(date_create(),DateInterval::createFromDateString('last month'),2);
foreach($dp as $dt) echo $dt->format("y:M:d"),"\n"; //or "y F d"
```

outputs:

- 09:Oct:20
- 09:Sep:20
- 09:Aug:20

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use date("F"); to get the full text representation of the date.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE INT

SET @STARTDATE = -12

WHILE @STARTDATE < 0

BEGIN

PRINT DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MM,@STARTDATE,GETDATE()))+' '+ DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(MM,@STARTDATE ,GETDATE()))

SET @STARTDATE =@STARTDATE+1

END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo date('F', strtotime('-2 month')), '<br>',
     date('F', strtotime('last month')), '<br>',
     date('F');
```

Comment: Remembering that "last" is simply a synonym for "-1", you should not double up on strtotime()'s when not necessary; this is just wasting cycles.

Comment: @Nathan Kleyn, I didn't about "-1 month" syntax, "last month" was just a guess that worked.

Answer (score -4):

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ENDDATE VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @A INT
SET @A=-12
SET @STARTDATE= DATENAME(MONTH,GETDATE())+ DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH,0,GETDATE()))
WHILE @A < 0
BEGIN 
SET @STARTDATE = DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,@A,GETDATE()))+' '+ DATENAME(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH,@A,GETDATE()))
SET @A=@A+1
PRINT @STARTDATE
END
```