# Can't get previous month from DateTime in PHP- Is this a (pretty big) bug?

Tags: php, datetime

I need to create functions in PHP that let me step up/down given datetime units.  Specifically, I need to be able to move to the next/previous month from the current one.

I thought I could do this using DateTime::add/sub(P1M).  However, when trying to get the previous month, it messes up if the date value = 31- looks like it's actually trying to count back 30 days instead of decrementing the month value!:

```
$prevMonth = new DateTime('2010-12-31');
```

Try to decrement the month:

```
$prevMonth->sub(new DateInterval('P1M')); // = '2010-12-01'
$prevMonth->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('-1 month')); // = '2010-12-01'
$prevMonth->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 month')); // = '2010-12-01'
$prevMonth->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('previous month')); // = '2010-12-01'
```

This certainly seems like the wrong behavior.  Anyone have any insight? 
Thanks-

**NOTE:** PHP version 5.3.3

Comment: Though it's probably just a typo here, `$prevMonth = new DateTime($'2010-12-31');` is a syntax error.

Comment: Does it have to do with what Rasmus is talking about here? Sounds like it... http://twitter.com/rasmus/status/29243336217 http://twitter.com/rasmus/status/29243723623 http://twitter.com/rasmus/status/29243824255

Comment: @Alex JL- Whoah don't know how you found it but that's it- specifically see this: http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#SEC120   Post your comment as an answer so I can give you credit!

Comment: @Alex good find. But using 'first day of' is not a solution if you just want to add/substract to a random date, not just the 31st or 1st.

Comment: @Gordon- All I'm looking for is how to get the next/prev month value, irrespective of date.  Since months are 'fuzzy units', there is no correct answer for '1 Month ago', but there should be one for 'last month'.  So automatically bringing the date to the 15th, as illustrated in the GNU docs, looks like the safest way.

Comment: @Yarin yeah, looks like it. Most interesting question today :)

Comment: @Gordon- thanks for the effort--

Comment: Yeah, it just sounded familiar because I follow Rasmus on Twitter! I've never worked with datetime, and unfortunately, I don't have time to write a real answer right now that makes sense because they're telling me to hurry up and get back in the kitchen (Thanksgiving! :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(Credit actually belongs to Alex for pointing this out in the comments)

The problem is not a PHP one but a GNU one, as outlined here:

[Relative items in date strings](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#SEC120)

The key here is differentiating between the concept of 'this date last month', which, because months are 'fuzzy units' with different numbers of dates, is impossible to define for a date like Dec 31 (because Nov 31 doesn't exist), and the concept of 'last month, irrespective of date'.

If all we're interested in is the previous month, the only way to gaurantee a proper DateInterval calculation is to reset the date value to the 1st, or some other number that every month will have.

What really strikes me is how undocumented this issue is, in PHP and elsewhere- considering how much date-dependent software it's probably affecting.

Here's a safe way to handle it:

```
/*
Handles month/year increment calculations in a safe way,
avoiding the pitfall of 'fuzzy' month units.

Returns a DateTime object with incremented month/year values, and a date value == 1.
*/
function incrementDate($startDate, $monthIncrement = 0, $yearIncrement = 0) {

    $startingTimeStamp = $startDate->getTimestamp();
    // Get the month value of the given date:
    $monthString = date('Y-m', $startingTimeStamp);
    // Create a date string corresponding to the 1st of the give month,
    // making it safe for monthly/yearly calculations:
    $safeDateString = "first day of $monthString";
    // Increment date by given month/year increments:
    $incrementedDateString = "$safeDateString $monthIncrement month $yearIncrement year";
    $newTimeStamp = strtotime($incrementedDateString);
    $newDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $newTimeStamp);
    return $newDate;
}
```

Comment: Your method is almost correct. You need to increment the month++ before using it. As `0, 0` would go back 1 month, and `1, 0` would print the same date and so on. So its basically off one month.

Comment: PS: wrote some test cases for it at https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/commit/b62c4d91f263d4882f80a69083b0347c518fc2d7

Comment: its wrong for me, since "may"  is not coming as previous month on june.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to achieve this in my opinion is using mktime.

Like this:

```
$date = mktime(0,0,0,date('m')-1,date('d'),date('Y'));
echo date('d-m-Y', $date);
```

Greetz Michael

p.s mktime documentation can be found here: http://nl2.php.net/mktime

Comment: It wraps years correctly, but not months. Running it on May 31, results in "01-05-2012"!

Answer (score 1):

You could go old school on it and just use the date and strtotime functions.

```
$date = '2010-12-31';
$monthOnly = date('Y-m', strtotime($date));
$previousMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($monthOnly . ' -1 month'));
```

Comment: This code needs a space in front of the '-1', and then it works (I downvoted it because thought it was broken, but now won't let me upvote until the answer is edited...?) So thanks, if you edit it I'll fix the vote

Comment: @Yarin - Sorry about that, new to this place.

Answer (score -1):

(This maybe should be a comment but it's to long for one)

Here is how it works on windows 7 Apache 2.2.15 with PHP 5.3.3:

```
<?php $dt = new DateTime('2010-12-31');
$dt->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
print $dt->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';
$dt->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('-1 month'));
print $dt->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';
$dt->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 month'));
print $dt->format('Y-m-d').'<br>';
$dt->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('previous month'));
print $dt->format('Y-m-d').'<br>'; ?>

2010-12-01
2010-11-01
2010-10-01
2010-09-01
```

So this does seem to confirm it's related to the GNU above.

Note: IMO the code below works as expected.

```
 $dt->sub(new DateInterval('P1M'));
```

Current month: 12
Last month: 11
Number of Days in 12th month: 31
Number of Days in 11th month: 30
Dec 31st - 31 days = Nov 31st
Nov 31st = Nov 1 + 31 Days = 1st of Dec (30+1)

Comment: I'm not following ya- The sample results you give have the same problem mine did: 2010-12-31 -1 month = 2010-12-01.  ?  And I'm working on Mac OS X btw

Comment: @Yarin, yes 2010-12-31 = 2010-12-01, in a weird twisted sort of way it makes sense. From a certain point of view it might not seem like a bug, but from others it does.

Comment: I've downvoted this because you only reproduced my results and did not offer any solution.

Comment: @Yarin that's fine, I did put at the top of the answer "(This maybe should be a comment but it's to long for one)" I wasn't looking for it to be an answer. BTW HOW did I get the SAME answers as you? ALL OF YOURS. Have // = '2010-12-01' listed at the END of them, I DID NOT GET THOSE RESULTS. HTF is that the same results as you? The first one was the same the other 3 were NOT.

Comment: Sb - mine are results for each of the examples run individually- you're just running them in sequence, but the point is to test each against a 31st date, in which case they produce the same result.  I think you misunderstand the question and the issue, read my answer.