# Get previous months from string

Tags: php, string, date

I need to echo 3 previous months from a string.

```
$monthyear = "01/2015";
```

OUTPUT

1. 12/2014
2. 11/2014
3. 10/2014

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get the current month and previous three months using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594277/how-can-i-get-the-current-month-and-previous-three-months-using-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go ahead and try the following:

```
<?php
    // Given string:
    $monthyear = "01/2015";

    // Init DateTime object:
    $datetime = new DateTime();
    // Create a new datetime instance, and parse given string:
    $date = $datetime->createFromFormat('m/Y', $monthyear);

    // Loop for 3 iterations:
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
        // Print current date:
        echo $i . ". " . ($date->format('m/Y')) . "<br>";
        // Reduce one month:
        $date = date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('-1 months'));
    }

?>
```

Yealds:

```
1. 01/2015
2. 12/2014
3. 11/2014
```

You can test this code in [phpfiddle.org](http://phpfiddle.org/)

*Sources:*

- PHP [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)
- PHP [date_add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: Thnk you sir..  this is very helpful

Answer (score 0):

So what you're trying to do here is get a *range* of dates (*3 months ago to now*) at a specific interval (*1 month*). This is easily done with something like PHP's [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/dateperiod) class.

First you need to create a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) object from that string, which you can do using something like [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat). This `DateTime` object can be used as your **ending range**.

```
$endRange = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat("m/Y", $monthyear);
```

Second, you can subtract 3 months from that `DateTime` object using [`DateTime::sub`](http://php.net/datetime.sub) in order to get the **starting range**. To do this you use a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/dateinterval) object to specify the interval of time you wish to subtract from the `DateTime` object.

```
$startRange = $endRange->sub(new DateInterval('P3M'));
```

Finally, you can create your `DatePeriod` object using the `$startRange` and `$endRange` along with a `DateInterval` of 1 month and traverse the object to get the 3 desired dates.

```
$period = new DatePeriod($startRange, new DateInterval('P1M'), $endRange);

foreach($period as $date) {
    echo $date->format("m/Y");
}
```

This should give you the desired dates `10/2014`, `11/2014`, and `12/2014`.